# Using ICS functions in an application targeted for Gingerbread

Tags: java, android

How does one incorporate functions from, let's say ICS or Jelly Bean while our application is targeted for Gingerbread? How to prevent the compilation errors I receive?

Like lets say I want my application to use something like- android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlend. I can not use this while the user is on Gingerbread but how do I enable an option for the ICS user to use it? When I code it for a Gingerbread targeted application, I get errors.

How do I prevent these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    // code for ICS and above versions
} else{
    // code for phones running an SDK before ICS
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html